# how can i login to my Azure VM with my AAD credentials?

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, virtual-machine, rbac

I'm trying to login to my Azure VM with my AAD credentials (login with Azure AD already enabled while creating the VM), a RBAC as " virtual machine administrator login " is also already assigned to this VM. im trying to login with RDP and with this form: 
username: AzureAD\username@work-domain.com 
password: my-password 
But i receive this error message : "The Sign-in method you're trying to use isn't allowed. For more info, contact network administrator". can anyone help?

note: i have already tryed with GPO but it didn't help out

Comment: Does your local machine join to the Azure AD with the same directory as the VM you want to connect?

Comment: yes the same one

Comment: How do you join your local machine to the directory as the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login to the Azure VM with AAD credential, you can follow the steps in [Sign in to Windows virtual machine in Azure using Azure Active Directory authentication (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows). And here is something important for you:

> Remote connection to VMs joined to Azure AD is only allowed from
>   Windows 10 PCs that are Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined to
>   the same directory as the VM. Additionally, to RDP using Azure AD
>   credentials, the user must belong to one of the two RBAC roles,
>   Virtual Machine Administrator Login or Virtual Machine User Login.

The local machine that you use to remote connect to the VM via the AAD credential needs to be joined in the Domain as your Tenant. On my side, I use the user of the Tenant and can connect to the VM successfully. For example, the Tenant is centoso.com, then the user should be username@centoso.com. And also, you need to check if the **AADLoginForWindows** extension is installed successfully for the VM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I could login via rdp to the AD joined VM with my AD Account credentials from my mac only when i disable MFA for my account.. but since that the disable for 2FA is not an option for me , i search for a methode allows me to login to VM from my joind mac and with enabled MFA.

Comment: @deaamo OK, for the MFA, do you see the troubleshooting for it in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#mfa-sign-in-method-required) I provide? You need to configure a strong authentication method such as Windows Hello.

Comment: yes, but i wanted to make the login possible with AAD accounts username/password and not such as face identifier, or fingerprint or something..
  so in this way it is not possible to do this so. isn't !?
note : i use for this purpose a registered mac in an AAD, and the VM, which i want to login onto, with windows 10 pro 1809 installed